# applescript to split multipage tiff

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to make a pdf of a multipage tiff file.
I managed to do that in windows with image magick.
In a project we are working together with a macbook with OSX (new to me).
And there should it be possible to.

Is there a script/automator... to do this.
Now I split the multipage tiff (2pages) in preview manually: open the tiff, drag each page to a folder and than I run a script to make a pdf.

Can that be done in a script?

Comment: "I managed to do that in windows with image magick." So why not use image magick again? Why is this an AppleScript question?

Comment: I'm not an administrator and the administrator doesn't like to many system changes

Answer (score 2):

**I greet every user** who tries to do without third-party applications where possible. The question asked by the OP is much more interesting than many of the trivial questions popping up in this section. Moreover, I do not understand the minuses put down by two users to the question asked. Here's the solution:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "QuartzCore"
use framework "Quartz"
use framework "AppKit"

property |NSURL| : a reference to current application's |NSURL|
property NSString : a reference to current application's NSString
property PDFPage : a reference to current application's PDFPage
property NSImage : a reference to current application's NSImage
property PDFDocument : a reference to current application's PDFDocument
property NSBitmapImageRep : a reference to current application's NSBitmapImageRep

-- select TIFF
set anAlias to choose file of type {"public.tiff"} with prompt "Select Multi-page tiff file"

-- get selected TIFF's  name and base name
tell application "Finder"
    set pathString to NSString's stringWithString:(name of anAlias)
    set baseName to (pathString's stringByDeletingPathExtension()) as text
end tell

-- make new destination folder (if it doesn't exist already)
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set destinationFolder to (make new folder at desktop with properties {name:baseName}) as text
    on error
        set destinationFolder to "" & (path to desktop folder) & baseName
    end try
end tell
set destinationFolder to POSIX path of destinationFolder

--Read Multi-Page TIFF
set aURL to |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:(POSIX path of anAlias)
set aImage to NSImage's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfURL:aURL
set aRawimg to aImage's TIFFRepresentation()
set eachTiffPages to (NSBitmapImageRep's imageRepsWithData:aRawimg) as list

-- extract each tiff page as PDF file
set pageNum to 1
repeat with curPage in eachTiffPages
    set thisImage to contents of curPage
    set aImg to (NSImage's alloc()'s initWithSize:(thisImage's |size|()))
    (aImg's addRepresentation:thisImage)
    --Make Blank PDF
    set aPDFdoc to PDFDocument's alloc()'s init()
    -- set PDF first page's content to next image
    (aPDFdoc's insertPage:(PDFPage's alloc()'s initWithImage:aImg) atIndex:0)
    -- write PDF to destination
    set outPutPath to destinationFolder & "/Page_" & pageNum & ".pdf"
    (aPDFdoc's writeToFile:outPutPath)
    set pageNum to pageNum + 1
end repeat
```

Comment: That is the spirit. I agree.

Comment: But like I said earlier, I'm totally new to Apple and Scripting. So how can I use this solution, because when I copy the  whole code to the scripteditor, nothing happens. Please help me from A till Z? I have version Mac OSX version 10.7.5 on a Macbook.

Comment: I Think I have version Applescript 2.2

Comment: In the mean while I've been able to run the script. I deleted use..., Use... at the beginning. I also needed to replace many times ": by ," and the code expected sometimes end instead of...... Error at the rule:         tell application "Finder"
 set pathString to NSString's stringWithString

Comment: I would like to post my code but it is too long. How to do this

Comment: Read **Cocoa-AppleScript Applets** on the https://macosxautomation.com/lion/applescript.html to understand  how to use my script on Mac OSX version 10.7.5

Comment: Remove **use AppleScript version "2.4"** from my script as well. I started for first time with OS X Capitan. So, I don't know how to help more with older versions. –

Comment: Can't you explain to me what the error means? Is it a question of the version? Remember I'm a totally newbe.

Comment: No, you have very **old version of OSX**. So, it can't run my code directly, as script. But you can save script as applet and run it any time like all other applications. Read the article I indicated to make applet. Opens one window were you can paste my code, then save as applet and use it with double click. Applet is just small application. The error is because my script uses ApplesScript Objective-C stuff (**AsObjC**), and in old OSX versions script editor can run it only as applet.

Comment: I think I did it as applet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233689/discussion-between-robert-kniazidis-and-adri).

Comment: We tried the solution of Robert on a newer version of osx and it worked. Thank you Robert. Can you or someone else help me to fine tune this? After the conversion I like to rejoin the two separate pdf's to one file and I want to run it automatacily when a file is added to a certain folder.